# decode Vigenere cipher that was encoded with Affine cipher

Tags: vigenere, affine-cipher

How do I decode some text that has been encoded like this: `affine(vigenere(text, vigenere_key), *affine_key)`? I don't know keys to either of them. At first I thought I could just bruteforce it by trying out all possible combinations, but then I realised that cracking Vigenere is based on finding keyword which can be literally anything and since the decoded message wont make any sense after cracking Vigenere as it is still encoded with Affine I'm kinda confused how do I find the right key to Vigenere and crack it?

Comment: What is the effect of affine to Vigenere?

Comment: @kelalaka well it encodes the result of vigenere cipher with affine cipher

Comment: That is obvious. What about the equations? $c_i = a (m_i +k_i) +b \bmod n$ where $k_i$ is the ith key of the Vigenere.